# 15GB of Android ADB files in tmp folder

Tags: macos, android, emulator, temporary-files, adb

Hi so I've noticed my HD space is running out rather quickly on MacOS and after a quick search I've found a 15GB temp folder at `/private/tmp/android-alex` with lots of similar files names like `adbcommandb1ff3f07-2d81-4f8a-8af2-e8f2d7285cef`

After deleting, they reappear after some time (of android emulator running)

Any idea what these are? And why they aren't deleted automatically? Even CleanMyMac doesn't seem to pick them up.

Content starts like:

```
Activity Resolver Table:
  Full MIME Types:
      application/com.google.android.gms.car:
        d38ff00 com.google.android.gms/.car.FirstActivity filter 7a9d4d2
          Action: "android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Type: "application/com.google.android.gms.car"
          AutoVerify=false
      application/vnd.android.package-archive:
        8f6c339 com.google.android.gms/.instantapps.routing.EphemeralInstallerActivity filter 91c2432
          Action: "android.intent.action.INSTALL_EPHEMERAL_PACKAGE"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Scheme: "file"
          Type: "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
          AutoVerify=false
      vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.googleplus.profile:
        7a2ad7e com.google.android.gms/.people.pub.PeopleProfileActionGatewayActivity filter fe1673a
          Action: "android.intent.action.VIEW"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Type: "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.googleplus.profile"
          AutoVerify=false
      text/plain:
        e9472df com.google.android.gms/.plus.sharebox.ShareBoxActivity filter cc8549
          Action: "com.google.android.gms.plus.action.SHARE_GOOGLE"
          Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
          Type: "text/plain"
          AutoVerify=false
```

Can upload full file if needed

Comment: You indicate you have an android emulator installed they are from that.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi yes I'm aware of that. After the details